# how to divide every value in a dataframe by a certain number if it's bigger than certain number

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have a dataframe of mixed values--it's very messy. I have values that are out of 10 rating and values out of 100 ratings. I want to normalize them to percentages.

My logic is if something is larger than 10 then I can divide by 100. And if something is equal or less than 10, I'll divide those values by 10.

current frame

```
col_1     col_2     col_3
 40        16        18
 2          9        20
 89         3        7.4
 23         8        34
```

new frame

```
col_1     col_2     col_3
 .40        .16      .18
 .20        .90      .20
 .89        .30      .74
 .23        .80      .34
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this example data frame

```
dd <- read.table(text="
col_1     col_2     col_3
40        16        18
2          9        20
89         3        7.4
23         8        34", header=T)
```

You can do this in base R with

```
myscale <- function(x) ifelse(x>10, x/100, x/10)
data.frame(lapply(dd, myscale))
```

or if you prefer dplyr

```
dd %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~if_else(.x>10, .x/100, .x/10)))
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help! I'm using dplyr and I didn't know about the `everything()` function. Thanks for the new tidbit!

Answer (score 0):

Similar logic as @MrFlick but without `ifelse` and `lapply` :

```
df/c(10, 100)[(df > 10)+1]

#  col_1 col_2 col_3
#1  0.40  0.16  0.18
#2  0.20  0.90  0.20
#3  0.89  0.30  0.74
#4  0.23  0.80  0.34
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked but I do prefer dplyr